# How to encrypt and decrypt Azure Storage Access Key

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight, access-keys

I have created Azure VM and installed my Java application in it and then connected to WASB storage.

I have added following jars and core-site.xml to access WASB storage from Java application.

- [azure-storage](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage)
- [hadoop-azure](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure)

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

    <property>
      <name>fs.AbstractFileSystem.wasb.impl</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.Wasb</value>
    </property>


   <property>
      <name>fs.azure.account.key.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME .blob.core.windows.net</name>
       <value>STORAGE ACCESS KEY</value>
   </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.azure.io.copyblob.retry.max.retries</name>
      <value>60</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.azure.io.read.tolerate.concurrent.append</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.azure.page.blob.dir</name>
      <value>/mapreducestaging,/atshistory,/tezstaging,/ams/hbase/WALs,/ams/hbase/oldWALs,/ams/hbase/MasterProcWALs</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>wasb://STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME@STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME.blob.core.windows.net</value>
      <final>true</final>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
      <value>360</value>
    </property>

  </configuration>
```

I have used Storage Access Key directly in core-site.xml. But I want Access key to be encrypted.

When I search about it, I got to know about below script:-

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.keyprovider.youraccount</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.ShellDecryptionKeyProvider</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.youraccount.blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>YOUR ENCRYPTED ACCESS KEY</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.azure.shellkeyprovider.script</name>
  <value>PATH TO DECRYPTION PROGRAM</value>
</property>
```

How do I access WASB storage with encrypted key. Is there a sample available for it for above configuration ?

Note:- I am connecting Azure VM directly to WASB storage without using HDInsight Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

KeyVault maybe the best choice for you to store the secret - keys.

https://kamranicus.com/blog/2016/02/24/azure-key-vault-config-encryption-azure/

Comment: Is there any other method available for this ?

Comment: If you don't like KeyVault, you can define any encryption mechanism you like:

e.g. 

<property>
  <name>[encrypted]fs.azure.account.key.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME .blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>encrypted value....</value>
</property>

In the parsing logic, if you find the property name start with [encrypted], decrypt it using certificate. The certificate can be installed to the VM when setting it up.

Comment: Do you have any sample encryption and decryption mechanism ?